# Display Popup of Click on Attachment Button in Android

Tags: android, popup, android-actionbar

How to design of this Screenshot.? Is it Possible for Actionbar open the popup menu(Display Screenshot) when click on Attachment button like WhatsApp?
       Please Suggest me.
       [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [popupwindow.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

In that you can make any custom layout and set it as content of your popupwindow.

Refer to this for a quick example [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)